# GitHub Action for Google App Engine (deliverables)

Tags: google-app-engine, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to set up a GitHub action to automatically deploy to Google App Engine when I push to the `master` branch. However, I am quite new in the pipelines. I tried to do my homework and I ended up stuck with this.

First, this is my `.github/workflows/main.yml`:

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to App Engine
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Google App Engine
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.4.0
        with:
          project_id: my-gae-project-id
          version: master
          credentials: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_KEY}}
          flags: --no-cache
          deliverables: app.yaml
```

Now I tried to create the `app.yaml` in the root directory and also in the `.github/workflows` directory. None of them works. For now, my `app.yaml` is just:

```
runtime: php74
env: standard
```

Here is the outcome of my GH action everytime:

[image: github screenshot]

I tried to do some research and found recommendation to put the `app.yaml` in a folder, so I also tried `.github/workflows/gae/app.yaml` and then set it as `deliverables: gae/app.yaml` - no success. Also tried to put the path in quotes like `deliverables: "gae/app.yaml"` - no success. Also tried to put the `app.yaml` to the root and set it as `deliverables: ../../app.yaml`. In some cases, the `app.yaml` creates a new GitHub action which is even more irritating.

Now I'm just getting frustrated, because I know this is going to be something silly, but I didn't find many resources about this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing step in your `main.yml` that's why your workflow can't find and access the files. To fix it, add [`checkout@v2`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action in your steps:

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to App Engine
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Google App Engine
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.4.0
        with:
          project_id: my-gae-project-id
          version: master
          credentials: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_KEY}}
          flags: --no-cache
          deliverables: app.yaml
```

You can also visit this **official** [github example](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine/blob/main/.github/workflows/example-workflow.yaml) for your reference.

Comment: Oh thank you, it moved me to another error though, but at least I'm moving somewhere! 

Comment: Your welcome! Please note if your `app.yaml` is placed in your root directory your deliverables should be `deliverables: app.yaml`